# How do I sum values based on a shared value in 2 separate rows and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I work on taking another companies data and making into a format we can use.
To figure out dues I have created a new table using this code.

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.memid ORDER BY a.nexttrandate DESC) as 'RowNum', 
    a.memid as 'memid' , 
    a.nexttrandate as 'date', b.status as 'status', 
    SUM(convert(decimal(18,2),a.price)) as 'price', a.billtoid as 'parentid'
INTO
    lame
FROM  
    arrr a 
JOIN 
    members b ON a.memid = b.memid
GROUP BY 
    a.memid, a.billtoid, a.nexttrandate, b.status;
```

What this table creates is basically a transaction history that also shows the next billing date. Which is why i do Rownum and order by transaction date so I can use RowNum = '1' to get the most recent.

This mostly accomplishes what I need.

However I get data that look like this.

```
memid    date   parentid    price
_____    ____   ________    _____
  1      2012       1        59
  2      2012       1        40
```

I need to add those 2 prices based on the parentid being the same as the memid. I dont mind if both values come out to 99 as another simple update and i can make the 2nd one 0

I found a thread and made a variation.

```
UPDATE lame
SET price = temp2.pricesum 
FROM lame
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT arrr.memid, SUM(convert(decimal(18,2),arrr.price)) as pricesum, 
arrr.billtoid, arrr.nexttrandate
FROM arrr WHERE arrr.nexttrandate = arrr.nexttrandate and arrr.billtoid = arrr.memid
GROUP BY arrr.memid, arrr.billtoid, arrr.nexttrandate) as temp2
ON temp2.memid = lame.memid;
```

Basically the arrr.billtoid = arrr.memid is where my naive mind is wanting to add those together but obviously that wont work. All it is referencing is when memid and billtoid is the same in a single row.

Is there any way to get the table above to add together?

Sorry for bad formatting.

Yes I realize I am probably making this harder than it needs to be.

Comment: I have never found mixing partition with group by to be what i needed.

Comment: Try `sum(convert(decimal(18,2),a.price)) OVER (partition by a.billtoid)`

Comment: Define the tables and what you need.  You show what you tried.  But "mostly accomplishes" does not define what you want.

Comment: Added some additional info.

Answer (score 0):

Given your output, isn't this the answer?

```
select A.memid, B.date, B.parentid, sum(B.price)
from ( [giant query] ) as A
join ( [giant query] ) as B
on A.memid = B.parentid
group by A.memid, B.date, B.parentid
```